# Question doesn't refresh when I close it

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

Just like the title says.  I have to refresh the page manually.

Don't know if this is affecting ordinary users on the fifth close vote or not (I'm a diamond moderator).

Comment: Remember back in 2005 when people never expected pages to refresh themselves? :P

Comment: I just went through the close queue until I found a candidate. It refreshed for me.

Comment: Worker for me a few minutes ago on SO, page refreshed as expected.

Comment: Confirmed. This is behaving the same way for me in FF on W7.

Comment: Happening for me too, Chrome on a Mac

Comment: Yes, it does happen to regular users (5th vote), it just happened to me now on a question right here on meta, and also as a moderator earlier today on another site.

Comment: It also happened to me twice yesterday

Comment: Happened to me too.

Comment: So the only ones affected are moderators (and @Lamak)?

Comment: Well it happened to me on SO, where I am not a moderator.

Comment: @ypercube I'm special (or so I've heard)

Comment: I have seen this behavior as well.

Comment: And to me on meta, where I am not a moderator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this over the weekend.

Please let me know if you see any more instances of this happening.

Comment: more instances: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227414/mod-closing-a-question-no-longer-refreshes-the-page-on-chromeium-33