# Mod closing a question no longer refreshes the page on Chrom(e)(ium) 33

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, moderator-tools

When I use my mod vote to close a question the page no longer reloads. This only appears to happen on Chrome/Chromium. I'm using version 33 on Ubuntu 13.10. I haven't tried Windows yet.

Firefox 28 and the mobile Chrome work fine, it's just the desktop version. If it's any help this has been happening for over a week now.

Comment: And **Opera** 12 on Vista

Comment: @random Opera 12 *and* Vista? I feel for you man.. Have some unicoins :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186119/question-doesnt-refresh-when-i-close-it

Comment: I've noticed this for several days now.  Thought it was a feature.  Oh, snap. I wrote up the last instance of this happening as a bug.

Comment: This is happening on a Question/Show page (e.g. this page)?  Working on OSX 10.9.2 and Chrome 33.0.1750.152.

Comment: @JarrodDixon Yes, when I close a question on the question itself.

Comment: Hmm, are you seeing any errors in Chrome's developer tools?

Comment: I'm downloading Ubuntu 13.10 desktop to try and repro... give me a bit :)

Comment: @JarrodDixon - I've been seeing the same on Safari on 10.9.2, as well. I know a bunch of the other moderators with various configurations have seen the same. The start coincided with one of the recent changes (maybe the separate flag handling capability?).

Comment: @BradLarson ah, good point - might be only on flagged questions... checking that.

Comment: Indeed, it is suddenly working for me on duplicate questions anyway. Searching for something to close as another reason...

Comment: Yep, got a repro on a flagged question - thanks @BradLarson.

Comment: Alright, managed to reproduce it again, but the question does indeed require a flag. (cc @JarrodDixon )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue with how the mod tools on a question page were being init'ed - the close functionality was being called twice.

A fix will be pushed out shortly.