# Closing a question no longer refreshes the page to show it closed

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, closed-questions, live-refresh

I think this started yesterday, when I close a question the page does not refresh to show the newly closed question. The closing works properly, and manually refreshing the page shows the page as it should be. (I'm a mod so my vote always closes the question; no idea if the same thing is happening for the fifth "normal" CV.)

This has the same symptoms as a problem as was reported and fixed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227414/278094) three years ago, so it must be a different issue.

Comment: Thank god. now I don't have to inspect and remove disabled property from submit answer button to post an answer I've written.