# What is considered a reasonable response time to a "Contact Us"?

Tags: support, contact

I recently sent a Contact Us message to inquire about disassociating a question from one of my accounts. I asked the question 4 days ago (September 27), it received an up-voted answer and the question itself has a positive score. However, for my own reasons (which I detailed in the message) I have submitted the request.

Having read some other posts on here about response, it seems the CM team is diligent about responding to these types of messages. So my question is what can be considered a reasonable response time? Should I wait a few more days?

---

**ETA**

Resolution was obtained on October 6, so the response time was 9 days.

Comment: Ah, the usual 6-8 weeks. ;)

Comment: It can indeed take several months, but usually takes few days. See official answer in dupe question.

Comment: You have to wait till they read the message and response to you. That is the reasonable response time. At present, all we can say is that.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd what did you mean by dupe question?

Comment: @redhand https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlTqm.png

Comment: @redhand your comment is just circular reasoning. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ah. The page needs a reload

Comment: @NVZ that's all we can say

Comment: also note that of those 4 days, 2 were in a weekend. SE is not a 24/7 shop.

Comment: @rene I'll put a call into their union representative to see if we can change that :P

Comment: @redhand you should have seen a banner "this question is closed" in the top.

Comment: I'd say it depends on the ticket. I'm currently waiting on my thing from more then a month ago, so have patience.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd previously it was there. But I didn't see that one for this Q.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think it is related to this https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301550/228134

Comment: @Magisch well, disassociating a post takes few minutes at worst, so no reason for them to delay that much unless the ticket gets lost somehow. (Which happens)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd should i rephrase the title of the question if I am really only looking a response specific to me? Or would that matter since if a CM did want to answer, they could open the post anyway?

Comment: @Skooba the later... I don't think it's proper to open a meta post for every contact request which gets delayed, and in the rare case it is, a CM can just post answer even while this is closed. :)